# UIPickerView is cut in the middle on iPad simulator only

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIView` with height = 1.0, and a picker view that is attached on it with Autolayout (it appears below the view).

My picker view's width should be equal as the line seperator (the UIView).

On iPhone it works great, but on iPad the picker view is sliced in the middle. 
I tested in the "Debug view hierarchy", and saw that it is actually in the width of the view, but still cut in the middle (see screenshot added).

I then thought that it may be a delegate function issue, so I added these implementations:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let rowInfo = getRowText(for: pickerView, fromRow: row, andComponent: component)

    let field = (view as? UITextField) ?? UITextField()
    field.font = font16
    field.textAlignment = .left
    field.textColor = .black
    field.text = rowInfo.text
    return field
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return self.aSeperator.frame.width
}
```

Screenshots:
[image: On simulator]

[image: on debug view hierarchy]

[image]

this are the autolayout constraints I implemented for that picker view
[image]

Comment: Could you check field frames what you return in `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {}` method. Just add `print(field.frame) `right before `return field`.

Comment: Can you post how you are attaching the pickerView with autolayout? Probably this could be the source of issue.

Comment: @manismku I edited my post adding another image showing the autolayout constraints.. I honestly do not think that is the problem but who knows

Comment: ok. Looks weird. how you are showing these pickerview.

Comment: There is a UITextField, and when it is begins editing, the picker isHidden property is set to false

Comment: i also added another picture that shows the frames in run time and shows that the width of the elements is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!
The issue was that I was calling this function on the `UIPickerView` from `viewDidLoad`:

```
    clientPickerView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 4.0)
    clientSitePicker.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 4.0)
```

This function makes changes to the mask of the picker view adding round corners to it (as seen in the images above):

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

The solution was to move this call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.